# Why are we have to declare float 2 times like " float x = (float)4.5; "

Tags: java

Why are we have to declare float 2 times like

```
float x = (float)4.5;
```

Comment: You're assigning a double literal to a float variable, and so the cast is needed. Better to do `float x = 4.5f;` using a float literal. Better still to avoid using float altogether. There is no need and you loose precision.

Comment: And you're not "declaring" float twice. You're declaring it once, `float x`, and casting it on the right, `(float) 4.5`.